# Python Non-recursive Permutation

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

Does anyone understand the following iterative algorithm for producing all permutations of a list of numbers?

I do not understand the logic within the `while len(stack)` loop. Can someone please explain how it works?

```
# Non-Recursion
@param nums: A list of Integers.
@return: A list of permutations.

def permute(self, nums):
    if nums is None:
        return []
    nums = sorted(nums)
    permutation = []
    stack = [-1]
    permutations = []
    while len(stack):
        index = stack.pop()
        index += 1
        while index < len(nums):
            if nums[index] not in permutation:
                break
            index += 1
        else:
            if len(permutation):
                permutation.pop()
            continue

        stack.append(index)
        stack.append(-1)
        permutation.append(nums[index])
        if len(permutation) == len(nums):
            permutations.append(list(permutation))
    return permutations
```

I'm just trying to understand the code above.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through it with a debugger?  A good way to understand an algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments section to your question, debugging may provide a helpful way to understand what the code does. However, let me provide a high-level perspective of what your code does.

First of all, although there are no recursive calls to the function `permute`, the code your provided is effectively recursive, as all it does is keeping its own stack, instead of using the one provided by the memory manager of your OS. Specifically, the variable `stack` is keeping the recursive *state*, so to speak, that is passed from one recursive call to another. You could, and perhaps should, consider each iteration of the outer `while` loop in the `permute` function as a recursive call. If you do so, you will see that the outer `while` loop helps 'recursively' traverse each permutation of `nums` in a depth-first manner.

Noticing this, it's fairly easy to figure out what each 'recursive call' does. Basically, the variable `permutation` keeps the current permutation of `nums` which is being formed as `while` loop progresses. Variable `permutations` store all the permutations of `nums` that are found. As you may observe, `permutations` are updated only when `len(permutation)` is equal to `len(nums)` which can be considered as the base case of the recurrence relation that is being implemented using a custom stack. Finally, the inner `while` loop picks which element of `nums` to add to the current permutation(i.e. stored in variable `permutation`) being formed.

So that is about it, really. You can figure out what is exactly being done on the lines relevant to the maintenance of `stack` using a debugger, as suggested. As a final note, let me repeat that I, personally, would not consider this implementation to be non-recursive. It just so happens that, instead of using the abstraction provided by the OS, this recursive solution keeps its own stack. To provide a better understanding of how a proper non-recursive solution would be, you may observe the difference in recursive and iterative solutions to the problem of finding n<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number provided below. As you can see, the non-recursive solution keeps no stack, and instead of dividing the problem into smaller instances of it(recursion) it builds up the solution from smaller solutions. (dynamic programming)

```
def recursive_fib(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    return recursive_fib(n-1) + recursive_fib(n-2)

def iterative_fib(n):
    f_0 = 0
    f_1 = 1
    for i in range(3, n):
        f_2 = f_1 + f_0
        f_0 = f_1
        f_1 = f_2
    return f_1
```

Comment: The previous algorithm is incorrect.  Try recursive_fib(1) it would fail.  It would generate recursive_fib(-1)? that was incorrect.  Plus the recursive calls should be added not subtracted.   I submitted an edit.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @ilim is correct and should be the accepted answer but I just wanted to add another point that wouldn't fit as a comment.  Whilst I imagine you are studying this algorithm as an exercise it should be pointed out that a better way to proceed, depending on the size of the list, may be to user `itertools`'s `permutations()` function:

```
print [x for x in itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3])]
```

Testing on my machine with a list of 11 items (39m permutations) took 1.7secs with `itertools.permutations(x)` but took 76secs using the custom solution above.  Note however that with 12 items (479m permutations) the `itertools` solution blows up with a memory error.  If you need to generate permutations of such size efficiently you may be better dropping to native code.